# $\int_n^{\pi-n} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx = \pi\ln\cot \frac{n}2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

(i) By substitution method, prove that
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-t)dt=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$
(ii) Prove that
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(\cot(\frac{x}{2})))=\frac{-1}{\sin(x)}$$

(iii) By using (i) and (ii), prove the above question.

I manage to solve (i) and (ii). But how to relate to part (iii). Integration by part seem not applicable here.

Comment: Regarding "prove the above question...", where is the question...?

Comment: @GaryMoore Probably the one on the title. I think it would be better if that were typed onto the body of the question as well.

Comment: sorry, is the title.

Answer (score 2):

If 1 is true, we have, let 
$$I=\int_{n}^{\pi-n}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}dx$$
and
$$I=\int_{n}^{\pi-n}\frac{n+(\pi-n)-x}{\sin(n+(\pi-n)-x)}dx=\int_{n}^{\pi-n}\frac{\pi-x}{\sin(\pi-x)}dx=\int_{n}^{\pi-n}\frac{\pi-x}{\sin(x)}dx$$
Adding both we get,
$$2I=\int_{n}^{\pi-n}\frac{\pi}{\sin(x)}dx$$
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{n}^{\pi-n}\frac{-1}{\sin(x)}dx$$
Also if 2 is true,
$$\int\frac{-1}{\sin(x)}dx=\ln(\cot(\frac{x}{2}))+C$$
See how it is related now?

Answer (score 0):

$(i)$ Let $a+b-t=x,\implies dt=-dx~~$ and the integral becomes $$
\int_a^bf(a+b-t)dt=\int_b^af(x).(-dx)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$ 
$(ii)$ $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(ln(\cot (\dfrac{x}{2}))=\dfrac{1}{\cot (\dfrac{x}{2})}.-
 cosec^2(\dfrac{x}{2}).\dfrac{1}{2}=-\dfrac{1}{\sin(\dfrac{x}{2}).\cos(\dfrac{x}{2}).2}=-\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$$
$(iii)$ for the third do the first part and the add the integrals and proceed appropriately

Comment: Note that the OP said he/she already knew how to do (i) and (ii).